# .NET Razor DropDownList value for ApplicatonUser Is Null

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to user the Identity ApplicationUser model as a foreign key in one of my entity framework tables. To populate the model for the razor view (C#), this is what I'm doing:

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();  
var users = context.Users.OrderBy(x => x.Email).ToList();
model.Users = new SelectList(users as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Id", Email");
```

And then in the view itself:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.User, Model.Users, "", new { required = "required" })
```

The view is populated correctly with the list of users. When selecting one and submitting the form, the "User" field is null. What is the correct way of integrating the ApplicationUser model within your custom EF context?

Comment: How are you submitting the form with selected value ? Other than that, your code looks fine except you do not need the safe casting to `IEnumerable` You can simply use `users`.

Comment: Just with a submit button (Html.BeginForm()). But the value for the User is null. I'm stumped.

Comment: You need to show use action method where the form is submitted (and you found the User property is null). and what type is User property ?

Comment: public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

Comment: **You need to show us the  http action method where the form is submitted and the definition of the parameters used for that**

Comment: That all works properly because it's in the view called Create and corresponds to the post for that action. I've debugged and it's going to that action correctly. I'll try adding it, though, for good measure.

Comment: Your SELECT element name will be "User" so you basically need to have a property with the same name in your view model/ parameter with the same name in your httppost action method for model binding to work

Comment: Still not working. Model is holding everything but the application user.

Comment: What Is the data type of your `User` property?

Comment: ApplicationUser

Comment: Why was this downvoted???

Answer (score 1):

you can do this 
in the controller

```html
ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName");
```

and in the view

```html
@Html.DropDownList("User", ViewBag.Users as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and in the post

```html
public ActionResult(Model m , string User )
{
  var user = db.Users.Find(User)
  var model = new Model 
   {
      User =user,
      etc, 
      etc...
   }
}
```

the 'id' of user in mi case is a string

[image]

Comment: are you saying that this will work instead of the DropDownListFor? Plus my User is located within a different context. I wonder if that's creating the issues.

Comment: yes it works for me  , look the images i edit my answer is a option

Comment: I didn't mark this as the answer because I'm already doing this, but trying to map ApplicationUser from the ApplicationDbContext and it will not hold the value.